# На какие разрешения экранов делать медиазапросы?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Как правильно прописывать медиазапросы и на какие разрешения экранов делать их?

Comment: Все зависит от ТЗ. Если вам указано что делать на все виды разрешения, делаете так, если указано что только для декстопов с этим играться, так как для мобильных будет отдельное приложение, делаете иначе. Тут или ТЗ, или если без него, то ваша логика (просто подумайте, где то что вы делаете будет применятся, т.е. условия). А вообще вам в ответе дали хороший шаблон, начните с него

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/ - стандарт и если необходимо, то + ваши собственные для корректного отображения контента

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, делать медиазапросы по этому шаблону, а если что-то будет не влазить или уплывать, добавлять промежуточные блекпойинты?

Comment: Жаль некоторые пользователи не принимают ответы(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так выглядят примерно обычно мои запросы

```
/* Large desktops and laptops */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {

    }

    /* Landscape tablets and medium desktops */
    @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {

    }

    /* Portrait tablets and small desktops */
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {

    }

    /* Landscape phones and portrait tablets */
    @media (max-width: 767px) {

    }

    /* Portrait phones and smaller */
    @media (max-width: 360px) {

    }
```

Comment: @НикитаФаст и почему же?

Comment: @НикитаФаст у меня лично все работает, в чем проблема, из ваших сообщений я понять не могу

Comment: @НикитаФаст да, верно

Comment: @НикитаФаст вы серьезно? Вам трудно изменять разрешение поля просмотра?

Comment: @НикитаФаст https://ibb.co/c7gGd0
https://ibb.co/ju6hJ0

Comment: @НикитаФаст вообще ничего не менял

Comment: но плюсик ваш всё равно